# Mapping over elements matching string

Tags: javascript, regex, template-literals, array-map

I have a map

**.map((item: { amount: number}) =>**

The issue is that object prop is not always amount but will start with that. so it could be

**.map((item: { amountTotal: number}) =>**

**.map((item: { amountConsolidated: number}) =>**

Is there a way to regex or partially match the string so the map function can cover all the object names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that. Destructuring only works with concrete keys, it cannot morph to change the key destructured based on the data.

If you have an array of mixed data *where only one* of the properties would be present, you can destructure all and then get the one with data. That way you can operate on all the items in the array:

```js
const data = [
  {amount:             1}, 
  {amountTotal:        2},
  {amountConsolidated: 3},
];

const result = data.map(({amount, amountTotal, amountConsolidated}) => {
  //pick the first one that exists
  const num = amount ?? amountTotal ?? amountConsolidated;
  
  //example mapping operation
  return num * 2;
});

console.log(result);
```

---

Alternatively, if you have a homogenous array where the data is all the same shape, you can create a function that will work with a plain value and then you can specify which property it should take it from:

```js
const data1 = [
  {amount: 1}, 
  {amount: 1},
  {amount: 1},
];

const data2 = [
  {amountTotal: 2}, 
  {amountTotal: 2},
  {amountTotal: 2},
];

const data3 = [
  {amountConsolidated: 3}, 
  {amountConsolidated: 3},
  {amountConsolidated: 3},
];

//curried mapper that will apply a function against a given property
const mapper = fn => prop => item =>
  fn(item[prop]);

//use a function that works with plain numbers
const someMappingOperation = mapper(num => num * 2);

//specify which property the number comes from depending on the array
const result1 = data1.map(someMappingOperation("amount"));
const result2 = data2.map(someMappingOperation("amountTotal"));
const result3 = data3.map(someMappingOperation("amountConsolidated"));

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
console.log(result3);
```